# How to pass ID from JavaScript to Laravel PHP script?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

i am technically new to javascript and trying to pass a value to php script to use it in where clause...

**Blade html**

```
                    <div class="tab-content blog_tabs">
                            <div class="tab-pane" name="schedule" id="" >
                                <?php
                                    $tabSchedule = App\Schedule::where('route_id',  )   
                                                    ->latest()
                                                    ->get();
                                ?>
                                @foreach ($tabSchedule as $schedule)
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $schedule->schedule_number}}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endforeach    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
        console.log(id);

        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('user.schedule.getId') }}",
                type: "GET",
                data:{'id':id},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {

                    var route_id = 1;
                    
                }
            });
        }    
    });
```

So here is a picture of what i want to pass:

[image]

As shown in the image I am trying to pass route_id to a Laravel PHP script to use it in a where clause.

Comment: You already posted your question today, don't do that please

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is impossible, since `php` is a preprocessor, processes request before page loads, and `JS` starts processing `onload`. You already have the workaround and that is ajax.

The approach is simple:

1. Load the page without the `$tabSchedule` variable.
2. Use ajax to fetch the variable from backend and then use `JS` to render the `$tabSchedule` on blade. Laravel offers various tools for this, and of course you can still use vanilla JS or jquery if that's your thing.
3. Use `JS` to apply filters by running an Ajax call to update the variable.

Answer (score -1):

you can't do that,
if you have this value you need to pass it to your view or save it in cookies to get it when you need.